# "UUID" and "handle" getting nil from payload.dictionaryPayload in didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch, callkit, pushkit

I am getting **UUID** and **handle** value nil from `payload.dictionaryPayload` in `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload`.

I am using **SINService** for calling and I want to integrate **CallKit** and **PushKit** for Sinch in my App.

My code ...

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type {

     // Process the received push

    NSString *uuidString = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"UUID"];
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];

    NSString *handle = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"handle"];
    bool hasVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload[@"hasVideo"];



    if (uuid) {
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [app endBackgroundTask:task];
        }];

        [self displayIncomingCall:uuid handle:handle hasVideo:false withCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:task];
        }];
    }

}


- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type {

    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: and where is the problem? there is no such value as `handle` so why do you want it?

Comment: @Lu_ I want to displayincoming call with  `[self displayIncomingCall:uuid handle:handle hasVideo:false withCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:task];
        }]; `

Answer (score 0):

The right way to handle voip calls with callkit is to pass the SIN payload to the sinch client.

Comment: thanks for your kind response. Can you please help me how can i pass SIN to sinch client using **SINService**

Comment: In the sdk download there is  sample implementationof callkit,

Comment: in SDK implimentation is done with SINClient but I am using SINService. SDK and demo of CallKit are done with SINClient.